# Trying to make an encryption method with if-statements

Tags: java, caesar-cipher

```
public static String encrypt (String h, int a) throws Exception
{
  h = h.toLowerCase();

  if(h.contains("a"))
  {
     data = data.replace("a", "c");
  }
  if(h.contains("b"))
  {
     data = data.replace("b", "d");
  }
  if(h.contains("c"))
  {
     data = data.replace("c", "e");
  }
  if(h.contains("d"))
  {
     data = data.replace("d", "f");
  }
  if(h.contains("e"))
  {
     data = data.replace("e", "g");
  }
  if(h.contains("f"))
  {
     data = data.replace("f", "h");
  }
  if(h.contains("g"))
  {
     data = data.replace("g", "i");
  }
  if(h.contains("h"))
  {
     data = data.replace("h", "j");
  }
  if(h.contains("i"))
  {
     data = data.replace("i", "k");
  }
  if(h.contains("j"))
  {
     data = data.replace("j", "l");
  }
  if(h.contains("k"))
  {
     data = data.replace("k", "m");
  }
  if(h.contains("l"))
  {
     data = data.replace("l", "n");
  }
  if(h.contains("m"))
  {
     data = data.replace("m", "o");
  }
  if(h.contains("n"))
  {
     data = data.replace("n", "p");
  }
   if(h.contains("o"))
  {
     data = data.replace("o", "q");
  }
   if(h.contains("p"))
  {
     data = data.replace("p", "r");
  }
   if(h.contains("q"))
  {
     data = data.replace("q", "s");
  }
   if(h.contains("r"))
  {
     data = data.replace("r", "t");
  }
   if(h.contains("s"))
  {
     data = data.replace("s", "u");
  }
   if(h.contains("t"))
  {
     data = data.replace("t", "v");
  }
   if(h.contains("u"))
  {
     data = data.replace("u", "w");
  }
   if(h.contains("v"))
  {
     data = data.replace("v", "x");
  }
   if(h.contains("w"))
  {
     data = data.replace("w", "y");
  }
   if(h.contains("x"))
  {
     data = data.replace("x", "z");
  }
   if(h.contains("y"))
  {
     data = data.replace("y", "a");
  }
   if(h.contains("z"))
  {
     data = data.replace("z", "b");
  }

  return h;
}
```

When I run this it does not replace the correct letters. I don't know how to fix this and was just looking for some help.

Comment: That's not javascript.

Comment: The replacement is going to be cyclic. As when you replace `a` with `c` later you are replacing `c` with `e` so the original data won't be encoded properly

Comment: Notice that all those statements are *executed in sequence* - not on the original `data` input!

Comment: Do *not* use if statements for this. The easiest way to implement a substitution cipher is using a dictionary/hash/associative array.

Comment: couldn't you just iterate through your original string and increment each char by 2 (looping back for 'y' and 'z')?

Comment: You could google "Java Caesar Cipher" to get some ideas of better implementations.

Comment: Also, you're changing the letters of `data`, but ultimately returning `h`, which is just the original input changed to lowercase.

Answer (score 2):

The way you encrypt your string make lettres replaced more than one time.
If you realy want to use 'if' statement, you can do it this way:

```
static String encrypt (String data)
{
    String returned = new String ("");

    for (char h: data.toCharArray())
    {
        if(h == 'a')
            returned += " a', 'c";
        if(h == 'b')
            returned += "d";
        if(h == 'c')
            returned += "e";
        if(h == 'd')
            returned += "f";
        if(h == 'e')
            returned += "g";
        if(h == 'f')
            returned += "h";
        if(h == 'g')
            returned += "i";
        if(h == 'h')
            returned += "j";
        if(h == 'i')
            returned += "k";
        if(h == 'j')
            returned += "l";
        if(h == 'k')
            returned += "m";
        if(h == 'l')
            returned += "n";
        if(h == 'm')
            returned += "o";
        if(h == 'n')
            returned += "p";
        if(h == 'o')
            returned += "q";
        if(h == 'p')
            returned += "r";
        if(h == 'q')
            returned += "s";
        if(h == 'r')
            returned += "t";
        if(h == 's')
            returned += "u";
        if(h == 't')
            returned += "v";
        if(h == 'u')
            returned += "w";
        if(h == 'v')
            returned += "x";
        if(h == 'w')
            returned += "y";
        if(h == 'x')
            returned += "z";
        if(h == 'y')
            returned += "a";
        if(h == 'z')
            returned += "b";
    }
    return returned;
}
```

But it's better to use a hash table for this kind of algorithm.

Comment: if you're going to use `if`, you should use `else if`.  That way, you don't check the entire alphabet even if the source letter is "a"

Comment: You're wrong. If you use 'else if' statement, only one letter will be replaced (the higher in the alphabet in this case), and the algorithm will stop. So the data will not be encrypted.

Comment: Let's pretend the first letter is a "b".  As it is right now, your code will do: is b == a?  nope.  is b == b? yep, add d as the next character.  is b == c?  nope.  is b == d?  nope..... etc.  Else if will make it jump to the end of that iteration of loop as soon as it finds a match.  aka: is b == a?  nope is b == b?  yep, add d as the next character.  Next char, please

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simpler way to do this particular encryption:

```
static String encrypt (String data)
{
    String encrypted = new String ("");

    for (char c : data.toCharArray())
    {
        char newC = c+2;
        if(newC > 'z')
            newC -= 26;

        encrypted += newC;
    }

    return encrpyted;
}
```

Comment: this is my preferred method